# browser default style

Tags: html, css, browser

do you know where can i get the browser stylesheet? I try to explain me better. I need to know the default style properties that the browser applies to elements (not a specific browser). Is there a web site that talks about this? If not, have you got any idea of how to get those informations in javascript? I don't want to do an application so i don't need standard or crossbrowser code.

I hope that someone can understand my question, anyway ask if i wrote something that is not clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Firefox on Windows, you can look for the "gre/html.css" file in the installation directory.

Also view the [W3C-recommended default stylesheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html).

Comment: Note that there exist browsers which doesn't really adhere w3 standards. Particulary the ones developed by a team in Redmond.

Comment: Note that they don't have to, as that section is informative. Microsoft is working on aligning with it, though.

Answer (score 3):

You can find all browser-specific CSS defaults [here](http://css-class.com/test/css/defaults/UA-style-sheet-defaults.htm). However, most of the decent "[CSS reset](http://www.google.com/search?q=CSS+reset)" stylesheets have already taken them all into account.

Comment: I sign Josh answer as the correct one because he wrote before you, but this is a great answer too thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a site that lists them all, but here's a link to a [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/) file that resets what browsers do so you can start with a clean slate.